# TSQL - Subselect to Create column and value from multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I probably didn't explain the title well but what I'm trying to achieve is the following:

I'm querying two tables devices and installed applications and returning all the applications that device has associated. I'm trying to figure out how to search the returned applications and if Office 2010 is found it returns something like a column called "OfficeAppInstalled" and a result of 'Office 2010 only' or if Office 2010 and Office 2013 are both found a result of "Office 2010&2013" is created.

My SQL is not very good and this fiddle is missing restraints but this is a primitive of the data getting outputed. [sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7175a/5/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7175a/5/0) I'd like a new column called 'OfficeInstalled' and from the code in sqlfiddler for Computer1 only one row would be resulted with the OfficeInstalled column with a value of Office 2010/2013.

Comment: Please provide your database structure, sample data, and expected data to help people understand your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please google and learn about the CASE expression in TSQL.

Comment: @TabAlleman, my first attempt was to use CASE. My thought was to store a value in a variable using += when the string was found. Something like this: `"OfficeInstall" =
  CASE
  WHEN ta.appName = 'Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010' THEN @appCount += 1
  WHEN ta.appName = 'Microsoft Visio Standard 2010' THEN @appCount += 2
  WHEN ta.appName = 'Microsoft Project Standard 2010' THEN (@appCount += 4)
  ELSE @appCount END, ` it doesn't like the add equals but had it liked them I would case appCount for the currect Office+App name combo.

Comment: CASE cannot be used to do math operations, it simply returns a value.   Do the math outside of the CASE, using the CASE to only return 1, 2, 4 or 0.

Comment: I checked the Add EQUALS operator is a real thing. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627392(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Ok, but you can't do that operation inside the CASE statements.   You have to move it to the outside of the CASE, and only use the CASE to return the simple numeric value.

Comment: I not sure if I know how to do the work outside

Comment: maybe this is something you can work with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7175a/8

Comment: @JamieD77 that is super freaking close to what I'm looking for! I could take that data into excel and create a column with the Only Office or Office + Visio data.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at your table structure it seems that the only way to do this would be to compare appname to a join on the same table comparing to appname by parsing through the string values. Using string parsing compares in SQL is in general, bad and inconsistent.

Assuming you have the ability to adjust/add to the table structure you could change TApplications to remove the join to TDevices.

Then you can create a joining table that joins TApplications to TDevices as a many to many and housing the version.

```
    CREATE TABLE TApplicationsTDevices
    (
     id INT IDENTITY Primary Key,
     ApplicationID int,
     DeviceID int,
     Version nvarchar(256),
     FOREIGN KEY (ApplicationID ) REFERENCES TApplications (id),
     FOREIGN KEY (DeviceID ) REFERENCES TDevices(id)
    )
```

Having a structure like this allows you to sort by application name as well as versions and you can easily group by application and combine each version into a single record.

Edit:
I misunderstood the question, here is the query that I believe you are looking for:

```
    select  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + appname
                   FROM TApplications ta2 
                   WHERE ta2.description = ta.description 
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS appname, 
            ta.description, 
            td.name
    from TApplications ta 
      join tdevices td on ta.TDevice_Index = td.id
    WHERE td.name = 'Computer1'
    GROUP BY ta.description, td.name
```

Here is working update to your Sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7175a/30/0

Comment: I'm pulling the information from an SCCM database. The query should fetch all the applications associated with a device resourceID. I then need to go through that list of applications and when two or more Office products are found I need the output to display a column with the computer name and a column that contains OfficeAppsInstalled. My preference being if Office 2010 and Visio found then OfficeAppsInstalled = Office+Visio